# How to print full page using Html2Canvas and JsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I wanted to save full page as pdf using html2canvas and JsPDF. none of the methods I ever tried seems to work.

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
        allowTaint: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
            pdf.save('invoice.pdf');
        }
    });
```

Currently this prints only the viewport

How to print full page/ container. or any other better alternatives?

Comment: why are you saving this as a PDF? do you just want to print the contents of the document?

Comment: some stylings aren't supported by native print option. that's why @AlanSutherland

Comment: @SibiRaj you can use `html2canvas` and `pdfmake`

Comment: does pdfmake has CSS support? @NikhilRadadiya. also my page has some angularjs functions

Comment: @SibiRaj you can convert html to canvas image and then you can generate pdf of canvas image

Comment: yes. I tried that. It is working but the biggest problem I am facing is that. The html2canvas converts only the viewable area. the content hidden below with scroll is being omitted

Answer (score 1):

Use the print media query

```
@media print {
      body, html {
          width: 100%;
          margin-top: 0%;
          display: block;
          height: 100%;
      }
}
```

Comment: if you find my answer helpful please accept and upvote it

Comment: the default print option has its limitations and variations across browsers. so looking for a better option